# Diagonal entries of symmetric matrices and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

suppose I have a symmetric matrix $S$ with diagonal entries $s_{jj}$. I'm trying to prove that none of these diagonal entries $s_{jj}$ can be be smaller than all the eigenvalues of $S$. My textbook tells me that if one of these diagonal entries were small than all the eigenvalues, then $S-s_{jj}I$ would have wholly positive eigenvalues and be positive definite - however that couldn't be the case because $S-s_{jj}I$ would have a zero on the main diagonal.

What I don't understand is how one can skip straight to $S-s_{jj}I$ having wholly positive eigenvalues.

Help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the eigenvalues of $S - \mu I$ are $\lambda_1 - \mu, \lambda_2 - \mu, \ldots, \lambda_n - \mu$ where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $S$. You can check this by noting that the eigenvectors of $S$ are eigenvectors of $S-\mu I$ and vice versa.

Comment: Yep - solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As $S$ is a symmetric matrix it is diagonalizable and we can write $D = U^{-1} S U$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix and $U$ an invertible matrix. Now you can transform
$$ S- s_{jj} I \to U^{-1} (S- s_{jj} I) U = D-s_{jj} I $$
which has the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $S$ minus $s_{jj}$ which are positive per definition.